# Is it possible to solve for a matrix using a system of equations?

Tags: linear-algebra

Let's say I have 3 linearly independent matrix-vector equations.

$A\mathbf{x_1} = \mathbf{b_1}$

$A\mathbf{x_2} = \mathbf{b_2}$

$A\mathbf{x_3} = \mathbf{b_3}$

Instinctively , I would try to set the equation like this

$\begin{bmatrix} A & 0 & 0 \\ 0 & A & 0 \\ 0 & 0 & A \end{bmatrix} \begin{bmatrix} \mathbf{x_1} \\ \mathbf{x_2} \\ \mathbf{x_3}\end{bmatrix} = \begin{bmatrix} \mathbf{b_1} \\ \mathbf{b_2} \\ \mathbf{b_3} \end{bmatrix}$

Is it possible to solve for the matrix $A$? And if so, how would I do that? Is there a name for this type of thing?

Comment: If $\{x_1,x_2,x_3\}$ is a generator of the vector space, you can determine the linear map and hence the matrix that induces it.

Comment: Hm, do you mind pointing me in the right direction on how to do that? The x's and b's are known, I just want to solve for A

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If $\{x_1,x_2,x_3\}$ is a base, then you have
$$A\begin{pmatrix}x_1&x_2&x_3\end{pmatrix}=\begin{pmatrix}b_1&b_2&b_3\end{pmatrix}$$
or
$$AX=B$$
then
$$A=BX^{-1}$$

Answer (score 1):

Yes there is. This process is called Gauss Elimination. Check it our [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gaussian_elimination).

Using Gauss Elimination you can solve 3 equations of 3 variables.